# do i need 2 sockets for multicast send and unicast read?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, multicast

i'm working on a client/server project using udp socket in C/C++ on Linux. On the server, it needs to write multicast and read unicast. On the client, it needs to read multicast and write unicast. Can't use 3rd party libraries. only GLIBC

Do I need 2 sockets for both client and server ? one socket for multicast and one socket for unicast ?

BTW, both ip address and port are given.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Here are my code,

### Server

```
// open a UDP socket
m_sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP );

if ( m_sock < 0 )
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: create socket failed ..." << std::endl;
    return( false );
}

m_saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
m_saddr.sin_port = htons(0);          // Use the first free port 
m_saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // bind socket to any interface

// Disable loopback
char loopch{ 0 };

int rc = setsockopt( m_sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (char *)&loopch, sizeof( loopch ) );

if ( rc < 0 )
{
   std::cerr << "ERROR: setsockopt( ) to disable loopback failed, rc = " 
                    << rc << std::endl;                                                                
   return( false );
}

// Set local interface for outbound multicast datagrams.
// The IP address specified must be associated with a local
// multicast capable interface.
m_localInterface.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );

rc = setsockopt( m_sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char*)&m_localInterface,sizeof(m_localInterface) );

if ( rc < 0)
{
   std::cerr << "ERROR: Setting local interface failed, rc: " << rc << std::endl;
   return( false );
}

rc = bind( m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&m_saddr, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ) );

if ( rc < 0 )
{
   std::cerr << "ERROR: binding socket to interface failed ..." << std::endl;
   exit( -1 );
}
m_saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
m_saddr.sin_port = htons( UDP_PORT );
m_saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( UDP_ADDRESS );
```

### client code

```
// open a UDP socket
m_sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP );
if ( m_sock < 0 )
{
   std::cerr << "ERROR: create socket failed ..." << std::endl;
   return( false );
}

m_saddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
m_saddr.sin_port        = htons( UDP_PORT ); // listen on port defined UDP_PORT    
m_saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // bind socket to any interface

// Disable loopback
char loopch{ 0 };

int rc =  setsockopt( m_sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (char *)&loopch, sizeof( loopch ) );

if ( rc < 0 )            
{
   std::cerr << "ERROR: setsockopt( ) to disable loopback failed, rc = " 
             << rc << std::endl;

    return( false );
}

rc = bind( m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&m_saddr, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ) );

if ( rc < 0 )
{
   std::cerr << "ERROR: binding socket to interface failed ..." << std::endl;
   exit( -1 );
}

// JOIN multicast group on default interface        
m_imreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr( UDP_ADDRESS );
m_imreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY ); // use DEFAULT interface

rc = setsockopt( m_sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (const void *)&m_imreq, sizeof( struct ip_mreq ) );

if ( rc < 0)
{
   std::cerr << "ERROR: Setting local interface error" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

socklen_t m_socklen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

while ( 1 )
{
    rc = recvfrom( m_sock, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 
            (struct sockaddr *)&m_saddr, &m_socklen );

    if ( rc < 0 )
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: receive multicast message failed ..." << std::endl;

         break;
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout << "Received multicast ..." << std::endl;                
     }
}
```

Comment: Are given as what? If they are the same for both purposes you can us the same socket.

Comment: Yes, I think you need two sockets for this.

Comment: @Barmar You think so why? You're mistaken, u less there is some unstated constraint.

Comment: Upvoted pointless unexplained downvote. Perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: I meant the ip address and port are known. I tried one socket for both multicast and unicast but both client/server can only sends. They weren't able to receive each other's messages

Comment: Illegible, as you can see. Don't do that. Edit into your question, where it should have been in the first place. Don't post code in comments. It's part of your question. Put it there.

Comment: very sorry. this is my first question

Comment: What IP address are you binding to? And why are you setting the multicast socket's interface to INADDR_ANY? That's what it already is by default. And INADDR_ANY is not a 'local interface'. And why are you connecting the UDP socket? If you do that, you can't send anywhere else with it.

Comment: UDP_ADDRESS is defined as "225.1.1.2" and UDP_PORT is defined as 10009 for testing. I tried to bind to the socket initially but it wasn't working so i tried connect instead w/o any luck as well

Comment: what should the socket settings for both client/server to have client receive from multicast and send on unicast. server to send muliticast and receive unicast ?

Comment: You need to bind the socket to INADDR_ANY and the port your multicast group is using. Do *not* connect it. You then need to join the multicast group, and you should then be able to both receive multicasts and send unicasts.

Comment: I just updated both the server and client code the way I understand how they should be from the examples online. the problem is they're receiving message from each other. Is that what you were referring to ? thx again

Comment: You've updated your code but you haven't fixed it as per the comments here. I fail to see the point of posting here if you're just going to ignore what you're told. 'Examples online' are dubious at best, especially when uncited. They are often wrong, and often produced for a different, often unstated, purpose. You need to stick to reputable documentation. There is no reason whatsoever to connect the socket here, and several reasons against. Ditto setting the multicast IF. You can't just cut and paste random pieces of code together and expect thm to work. You have to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your feedback. I just figured out why I'm not receiving messages. I disable loopback in my code and my Ubunutu desktop doesn't have 2 network cards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with one socket per process.  You should set everything up as if you were only receiving (don't call `connect()`), then use `sendto()` to send datagrams to a specified address.

Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/3/sendto